# Help applying scaled bones to rest pose... without applying armature modifier

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, transforms, pose-mode

We have a character that was made using HumanGenerator. The face was prepared for ARKit which removed the facial rig and converts it to Shape Keys to work with mocap

Then we wanted to adjust some proportions of the body of the model so we scaled the bones, which the mesh is parented to.

Now I want to apply these bone transformation to the rest pose but I can’t find a way to do this. Every time we apply it the mesh reverts to the way it was before we scaled the bones

Because of the facial shape keys (which work flawlessly with mocap) I am not able to apply the armature modifier on the mesh.

I feel like there should be a method to simply apply the scale for individual bones but I have tried every method and can’t get it to work. Every time I apply the scale of any bone it will revert the mesh back to the way it was before

Is there a way to do this without applying the armature and re-rigging from scratch?

Any ideas? Thanks

[image: Selecting scaled bone]

[image: Applying scale or setting as rest pose]

Comment: There is no other way. Apply the Armature to the model, then In Pose Mode try Pose->Apply->Apply Pose as Rest Pose or any of the remaining options. Then reapply the new rest pose as Armature modifier to the model. It will keep all its vertex groups named correctly so no re-rigging required